# Opentk Camera rotation destroys scene objects rotations

Tags: c#, opengl-es, opentk

I fight with that for 2 days and searching internet but i don't have any answer for my problem. In few words i want to have orbiting camera on screen and objects which I want also rotate independently from my camera. I implement Arcball rotation controller and I use it to rotate all object in the scene (maybe this cause problem). It looks ok when i have camera in starting point but when i start moving it and I want to rotate objects on the scene its looks like all object rotate like im in the camera starting point. Maybe here someone can help :D

My Arcball class:

```
public class ArcBallGL{

    private bool isBeingDragged;

    private Vector3 downPoint;
    private Vector3 currentPoint;
    public Vector3 BallCenter { get; set; }
    private Quaternion down;
    public Quaternion Now { get; set; }

    private float width, height;

    public ArcBallGL()
    {
        Reset();

        width = height = 0.0f;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        isBeingDragged = false;

        downPoint = Vector3.Zero;
        currentPoint = Vector3.Zero;

        down = Quaternion.Identity;
        Now = Quaternion.Identity;
    }

    public void SetWindow(float width, float height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(float x, float y)
    {
        isBeingDragged = true;
        down = Now;
        downPoint = ScreenToVector(x, y);
    }

    public void OnMove(float x, float y)
    {
        if (isBeingDragged == true)
        {
            currentPoint = ScreenToVector(x, y);
            Now = down * QuatFromBallPoints(downPoint, currentPoint);
        }
    }

    public void OnStopDrag()
    {
        isBeingDragged = false;
    }

    public Matrix4 GetRotationMatrix()
    {
        return Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion(Now);
    }

    public Matrix4 GetRotationMatrixFormViewPort(Matrix4 camera)
    {


        var viewMatrix = Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion(Now).Inverted();
        viewMatrix.Normalize();
        return viewMatrix * Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion( camera.ExtractRotation()).Inverted();
    }

    private Vector3 ScreenToVector(float screentPointX, float screenPointY)
    {
        float x = (screentPointX - width * 0.5f) / (width * 0.5f);
        float y = (screenPointY - height * 0.5f) / height;
        float z = 0.0f;

        float mag = x * x + y * y;

        if (mag > 1.0f)
        {
            float scale = 1.0f / (float)Math.Sqrt(mag);

            x *= scale;
            y *= scale;
        }
        else
        {
            z = (float)Math.Sqrt(1.0f - mag);
        }

        return new Vector3(-x, y, -z);
    }

    private Quaternion QuatFromBallPoints(Vector3 from, Vector3 to)
    {
        float dot = Vector3.Dot(from, to);
        Vector3 part = Vector3.Cross(from, to);
        return new Quaternion(part.X, part.Y, part.Z, dot);
    }
}
```

My Camera class:

```
public class Camera{
    public Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero;

    private Vector3 Up = Vector3.UnitY;
    public float MoveSpeed = 0.2f;
    public float RotationSpeed = 0.01f;

    public Quaternion RotQuar { get; set; } 


    public Camera(Vector3 startPos = new Vector3())
    {
        Position = startPos;
        RotQuar = Quaternion.Identity;
    }

    public Matrix4 GetViewMatrix(Vector3 target)
    {
        //RotQuar.Conjugate();
        var rotMatrix = Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion(RotQuar);

        var camPosition = Vector3.Transform(Position, rotMatrix);

        var camDir = target - camPosition;
        camDir.Normalize();
        var camRight = Vector3.Cross(camDir, Vector3.UnitY);
        camRight.Normalize();
        var camUp = Vector3.Cross(camRight, camDir);
        camUp.Normalize();

        var cameraMat = Matrix4.LookAt(camPosition, target ,  camUp) ;

        return cameraMat;
    }
}
```

My mouse move methood

```
private void MouseMoved(object sender, MouseMoveEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Mouse.IsButtonDown(MouseButton.Left) && RIsDown)
        {
            foreach (Shape s in _shapes)
            {
                if (s.IsSelected)
                {
                    Rotation.OnMove(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y);
                    s.RoatationQuat = Rotation.Now;
                    s.RotationMatrix = Rotation.GetRotationMatrixFormViewPort(_camera.GetViewMatrix(Vector3.Zero));
                }

            }

        }
        if (e.Mouse.IsButtonDown(MouseButton.Left) && CIsDown)
        {
            Rotation.OnMove(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y);
            _camera.RotQuar = Rotation.Now;
        }

    }
```

I use index buffer to draw my objects on the scene. I think the problem lies in calculating the camera coords to objects coords but i don't know where i must calculate it. Thanks for help